# How to encode the following string “ + ” in an URL to open a PDF file

Tags: urlencode

Hi i have to urlencode a link to a PDF file which includes the string " + ". My urlencode function in my database, encode this to "%20%2B%20" and i get a 404 ERROR that the file is not found.

f.e. http://example.com/test + test.pdf to http://example.com/test%20%2B%20test.pdf

Comment: Is there any reason why PDF name isn't `test-test.pdf`? Encoding to `%20%2B%20` should work too.

Comment: Unfortunately i can not change the filename. When i click on the link it doesn't decode, i get "http://example.com/test %2B test.pdf"